# Table isn't showing up as a FK dependency (dotted line assoc) when added to .edmx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a TableA that includes a TableBId dependency.  When I try to delete and re-include TableB my .edmx is still not showing an association between TableA and TableB.  My db is FK relationthip in the db looks fine.

Any ideas? When I try to add the Navigation property to the table it won't let me select the "Select Association" the property as I thought I could manually add the association within the .edmx.

Comment: Maybe post your create script for the problem FK / table(s).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've really customized the entity, delete both and right click and add again from the database.